# Progress Bar Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I have a website where the user is typing in a start and end point in a form at the index.html page.
When the user clicks submit the data is sent to the backend where several API request and calculations are going on. 
When everything is ready an new page opens with the result in the result.html page

Sometimes the process takes up to 10 seconds and the website just stays at the index.html without any sign whats going on in the backend. So the user often closes the page because he thinks nothing happens.

Is there a way I can add a progess bar (from 0% to 100%) at the index.html page?

Comment: If it's one call to the backend server, no, you can't give a progress bar easily. Most sites will just have a loading wheel in this case. If you make, for instance, 5 different API calls and have them chained (promised), you can make each of the completions update a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp

Ex:

```
<progress value="22" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: And how will the OP update this progress bar to match the percentage of processing done on the back end?

Comment: OP provided no information or code on his backend, nor how the processing happens. Generalized questions can only receive generalized answers

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted. It is what the guy asked for. A loading gif would be better however

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loading icon or gif 
http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/
hope this helps you